# ` key on a Windows keyboard - on mac os

Tags: macos, keyboard

I'm new to mac os, and use a Windows keyboard.
It worked fine, but suddenly (I don't know when exactly) the key "`" (above the Tab key) has turned into "§".

Also when using Shift, this key write "±" instead of "~"

Does anyone know why it happens, and how can I fix it?

Comment: What Language is the keyboard set to? § above Tab is UK English, ` above Tab is US English. Another test is shift/3 vs alt/3 UK shift/3 gives £, US gives #

Comment: Thank you! I've tried to change the keyboard type and chose it again (US), and the problem disappeared!

Comment: Glad it helped. Let me see if I can squeeze that into an answer, for sake of completeness...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That could likely be that the keyboard language is set incorrectly.

As a rough guide, § above Tab is UK English, ` above Tab is US English. 
Another test is shift/3 vs alt/3 UK shift/3 gives £, US gives #

Try changing the input language. You can see the results in the prefs pane before committing.

[image]